# Seleccionar el Valor de un Dictionary en un ComboBox Wpf

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, wpf, combobox

tengo el siguiente código.

```
ajusteCbb.ItemsSource = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "A", "SI" }, { "C", "NO" } };
ajusteCbb.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
ajusteCbb.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
```

y en un Datagrid tengo este codigo

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ajusteCbb" Header="Ajuste" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Ajuste}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Entonces con eso ya muestro los valores en el combobox y lo selecciono.

El problema es que cuando miro lo que selecciono, tomo lo siguiente

```
[C, NO]
```

Pero si le dije que el selectedvaluepath era key por que no me esta tomando C como valor??? que tengo mal??

Comment: el origen de datos que asignas al DataGrid, puedes validar que la propiedad "Ajuste" tome valores como ser "C", porque sino lo hace no va a seleccionar el item del combo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion era cambiar SelectedItemBinding por

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=IdUnidadMedida}"
```